# Is $H_2O$ the only compound which has a density anomaly?

Tags: thermodynamics, water, physical-chemistry, density, phase-diagram

My question is simple: are there any elements, compounds or materials other than water ($H_2O$) which have a density anomaly characterized by a turning point in the $T-\rho$ curve?

Comment: Bismuth, silicon, gallium, antimony and germanium also all expand upon freezing, for example. Around this region, increased pressure will promote melting, which seems to correspond to what you're asking about.

Comment: And don't forget also plutonium...